# SharedPreferences Data Still Will Not Update TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences

I have an activity class which will scan an NFC tag and assign it to a string (this part is functioning fine) the string is then shared via sharedpreferences which then updates a textview (among other things). For some reason the textview never seems to update with the text from the NFC tag. It should be a simple enough problem to solve - I simply cannot get the NFC data which is assigned to a string to update the textview via sharedpreferences and I'm not sure why.

CONNECT.JAVA CODE SNIPPET:

```
   // after scanning - splitting the message by comma
          String[]tagdata=msgtext.split(",");

        String networkSSID = tagdata[0].toString();
        String networkPass = tagdata[1].toString();
        String time = tagdata[2].toString();
        String restricted = tagdata[3].toString();
        String corename = tagdata[4].toString();





        String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
     //   editor.putBoolean(time, true);
        editor.putString("time", time);
        editor.putBoolean(restricted, true);
        editor.putBoolean(corename, true);
        editor.commit();
```

RULES.JAVA CODE SNIPPET: (where the time textview is shown - but never changes)

```
    String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    boolean name = prefs.getBoolean("name", true); 
    boolean code = prefs.getBoolean("corename", true);
    //boolean time = prefs.getBoolean("time", true);
    String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
    boolean ssid = prefs.getBoolean("restricted", true);
    Time.setText(String.valueOf(time));
//String time = String.valueOf(time);



       Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
        PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                time ? 1000 : 0, pintent2);
```

Comment: You're reading a different SharedPreferences file than you're writing to.

Comment: I don't understand your above comment. But you should have a close look at how you open the shared preferences files. You're not specifying a file name for one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editor.putString("name", name)` and so on  and prefs.getString("name", "");

Instead of

`SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

in CONNECT.JAVA you should use

`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

When you call `getPreferences` the preference is private to the activity.

Comment: I updated my source code above as suggested (thanks - that was a pretty big problem!) but I still can't get the textview to update with the new data : (

Comment: After I scan the NFC tag - the textview still will not update with the scanned text via SharedPreferences

Comment: Now I'm getting a nullpointer error on = Time.setText(String.valueOf(time));


...and still no updated textview : (

Comment: That means Time is null, let me look.

Comment: You have not findViewById for Time

Comment: time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time); ? : )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28637/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-bill-florentine)